# Add client-side Blazor to existing Asp.Net Core 3.1 App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to render a client-side Blazor App in a view of a controller of an existing Asp.Net Core 3.1 App.

I started following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and I created an empty app from the template.
I found out that what I need is:

1. These nuget packages:

   ```xml
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DevServer" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" />
   ```
2. This code in `Program.Main`:

   ```cs
   var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
   builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
   await builder.Build().RunAsync();
   ```
3. This HTML code in the *View* for the Blazor App 'entry point':

   ```html
   <app>Loading...</app>

   <div id="blazor-error-ui">
       An unhandled error has occurred.
       <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
       <a class="dismiss"></a>
   </div>
   <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
   ```
4. The `.razor` components:

   - App.razor
   - _Imports.razor
   - Shared/MainLayout.razor
   - Shared/NavMenu.razor

This should be it, but I get the error (can add full stack trace if you need):

```
---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
```

Where can I find that nuget package version? Do I need an assembly binding?
I tried without success with:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.0" />
```

**EDIT**

Adding the following packages solved that issue:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.2.0" />
```

But now I have a different error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.Component.targets(106,5): error : rzc generate exited with code 1.
```

And Visual Studio (16.4.4) crashes as soon as I open any `.razor` file

Comment: Do you have 2 projects, one for the blazor app and one for your server ?

Comment: No, I'm trying to put everything in the same project. Do I need 2 separate projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following packages in your project :

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Server" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" />
```

In your `Startup.Configure` method add:

```cs
app.UseClientSideBlazorFiles<BlazorApp.Program>()
   .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
       endpoints.MapFallbackToClientSideBlazor<BlazorApp.Program>("blazor");
   });
```

> Where "blazor" is the relative uri to your razor view hosting the blazor app.
> and `BlazorApp.Program` the type of your blazor app `Program`

If you want it in 2 separates projects then the Blazor app project must have those packages :

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DevServer" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" />
```

and the server project this one :

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Server" Version="3.2.0-preview1.20073.1" />
```

Comment: Hi, I did what you say but now Visual Studio crashes every time I try to open any view (.cshtml, .razor) and the build returns `error : rzc generate exited with code 1.`

Comment: @MichelemppMarostica delete bin and obj folders. Build with `dotnet build` command line and fix all issues.

Comment: Thank you, it is now compiling and the website starts again. Now I'm getting a 404 on `_framework/blazor.server.js` when I try to load the Blazor App

Comment: The generated html code must contains a `<base href="/" />` tag in the html `<head>` section. If not, the application try to download scripts and dlls relative to the current url. Add it in your `*_Layout.cshtml*

Comment: I added it to the shared layout, my mistake was that the js file is `_framework/blazor.webassembly.js` not `blazor.server.js`. Thanks again

Comment: Is there a way to select the assemblies that are included in the Blazor Client side App? I'm asking because I have some project/package references at stuff I don't need in the Blazor app and don't want to be shipped, some of them are framework/core dlls that are not compatible with mono

Comment: You should ask it in a new question